# Unable to mock ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextFloat()

Tags: java, random, mocking

I wanted to unit test `shouldEnforce` method in `Enforcer` class by faking the out of `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextFloat()` to some predetermined values. But I keep getting this error in the terminal.

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException:
> when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
> For example:
> when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

```
public class Enforcer {
  private static final ThreadLocalRandom random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
  private double ratio;
  public Enforcer(double ratio) {
    if (ratio < 0 || ratio > 1) {
      return;
    }
    this.ratio = ratio;
  }

  public boolean shouldEnforce() {
    float randomValue = random.nextFloat();
    return (randomValue < ratio);
  }
}
```

Here is my unit test in a separate file,

```
@PrepareForTest({ Enforcer.class}) // <- not sure if needed. Please comment
public class TestEnforcement {
  private static ThreadLocalRandom random;

  @Before
  public void setup() throws Exception {
    random = mock(ThreadLocalRandom.class);
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(ThreadLocalRandom.class);
    when(ThreadLocalRandom.current()).thenReturn(random);
  }

  @Test
  public void testEnforcer() {
    when(random.nextFloat()).thenReturn((float) 0.5);
    Enforcer enforcer = new Enforcer(0.51);
    assertTrue(enforcer.shouldEnforce());
  }
}
```

The above error is caused by the `when` statement in @Before method. But if I take out that line, the assertion will fail when `nextFloat()` generates values that are greater than 0.51, so random object is being mocked out.

**Update**: I was able to fix the error by adding the correct anotation in the unit test.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Enforcer.class})
public class TestEnforcement {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your need to prepare test case for working with PowerMockito by applying the following two annotations:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ Enforcer.class})
public class TestEnforcement { 

}
```

Without these annotations mocking will not work.
You have missed: `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`

Classes needed to be defined using `@PrepareForTest` annotation are typically those that needs to be byte-code manipulated. This includes final classes, classes with final, private, static or native methods that should be mocked and also classes that should be return a mock object upon instantiation.

`Enforcer` class is using static mock, so `@PrepareForTest` is required.

According to documentation:
https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.powermock/powermock-core/1.6.5/org/powermock/core/classloader/annotations/PrepareForTest.html

Please note, if you are using junit3 `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` annotation should be replaced with:

```
 public static TestSuite suite() throws Exception {
     return new PowerMockSuite(TestEnforcement.class);
 }
```